# Is there single-line LINQ way to do this?

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine an input text file with the format:

```
blaha|blahb
blahc|blahd
```

i.e. a pipe separated file with 2 columns. Right now, I'm loading it like this:

```
File.ReadAllLines(...).Select(x =>
{
   string[] arr = x.Split(new char[] { '|' });
   return new Item(arr[0], arr[1]);
};
```

If I change the first line to `.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '|' })` it's going to return every row and column as an array element which is not what I want. Is there a linq "inline" way to split the columns and new up the object?

Comment: You need to use `SelectMany` on the outermost `.Select` statement.

Comment: Not quite an answer to your original question, but one 'cooler' way to do it is to use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` so as to avoid the allocation of a potentially large (and unnecessary) array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cooler" is about as opinion-based as it gets, but you can't argue that this isn't LINQ, or that it has more than one semicolon.

```
var items =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines(myfile)
    let arr = line.Split(new char[] { '|' })
    select new Item(arr[0], arr[1]);
```

[Here's a filddle demonstrating the above code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uBq3L1). [`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(string path)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `string[]` -- an array of lines from the file.

Answer (score 6):

You can chain multiple selects together.

```
File.ReadAllLines(...)
    .Select(line => line.Split(new [] { '|' }))
    .Select(arr => new Item(arr[0], arr[1]))
```

One thing i do for this type of work as well is to create helper methods that you can use as Method Groups if this type of functionality is going to be reused.

```
public class Item {
    ...
    public static Item FromPipeDelimitedText(string text) {
        var arr = text.Split(new [] { '|' };
        return new Item(arr[0], arr[1]);
    }
}
```

then

```
File.ReadAllLines(...).Select(Item.FromPipeDelimitedText);
```

with this method the functionality that extracts the data from the file can be tested independently

Comment: `char` is superfluous - `new[] { '|' }` is enough.

Comment: @BartoszKP So is the `new[]` since `Split` takes `params` it can just be `Split('|')`

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this:

```
File.ReadAllLines(someFileName)
    .Select(x => x.Split('|'))
    .Select(a => new Item(a[0], a[1]));
```

This however assumes that the line **always** splits in [at least] two, which from personal experience is not easily error-handled.

I would suggest avoiding a single-line approach unless you are absolutely sure there will be no problem lines or use a function delegate to manage the instantiation and error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectMany`.

```
// returns IEnumerable<Item>
File.ReadAllLines(...).SelectMany(x =>
{
   string[] arr = x.Split(new char[] { '|' });
   return new Item(arr[0], arr[1]);
}
```